# Let's Encrypt certificate for 365 days

Tags: linux, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I am trying to create a **SSL** certificate, but due to some reason i am only allowed to create certificate for 90 days.
I would like to create a **SSL** certificate which lasts for 365 days.
Note: I already own a domain name.

System that i am using : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Let's Encrypt documentation:

> What is the lifetime for Let’s Encrypt certificates? For how long are they valid?
>   **Our certificates are valid for 90 days**. You can read about why [here](https://letsencrypt.org/2015/11/09/why-90-days.html).
>
> **There is no way to adjust this, there are no exceptions**. We recommend automatically renewing your certificates every 60 days.